# Moving a clipped canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

How would I go by if I wanted to move my clipped canvas? I need to move them to a specific area, but I'm not sure where to put the coordinates. I'm still very new to this, and would appreciate any help I can get.

I know I can make a "var" for the position, but since I have 6 pieces to move that would mean an awful lot of var's. Is there a simpler way?
Code:

```
<script> 
    var can=document.getElementById("NewCanvas");
    var Jctx=can.getContext("2d");
    var ctx=can.getContext("2d");
    var img = new Image();

    img.onload = function() {

    ctx.moveTo(305,307);
    ctx.lineTo(560,152);
    ctx.lineTo(450,10);
    ctx.lineTo(305,10);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.clip();
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0); // new image is clipped;
    }
    img.src='Prototype22.png';
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here's how to move a clipped area to a desired offset.**

Put your clipping coordinates in an array:

```
var clips=[{x:305,y:307},{x:560,y:152},{x:450,y:10},{x:305,y:10}];
```

Then pass the image, clipping-coordinates & desired offset [x,y] to a function that does this:

- Calculates the minimum `x` & `y` in the clipping coordinates array.
- Translates (moves the whole canvas) to `-minX+offsetX` & `-minY+offsetY`. This will both normalize the clipped area to [0,0] and also then move that normalized area to the desired offset coordinate.
- Defines the clipping path using the unaltered clipping coordinates.
- Creates the clipping area with `context.clip`
- Draws the image at [0,0]

The result will be a clipped area of the image that has been moved to the desired offset.

If you have multiple clips then you can create multiple arrays of clipping coordinates and pass them each into `drawClippedImgAtXY`.

**Here is example code and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var clips=[{x:305,y:307},{x:560,y:152},{x:450,y:10},{x:305,y:10}];

var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  drawClippedImgAtXY(img,clips,100,20)
}
img.src='https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/city-q-c-640-480-5.jpg';


function drawClippedImgAtXY(img,clipPts,x,y){
  var minX=10000000;
  var minY=10000000;
  for(var i=0;i<clipPts.length;i++){
    var pt=clipPts[i];
    if(pt.x<minX){minX=pt.x;}
    if(pt.y<minY){minY=pt.y;}
  }

  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(-minX+x,-minY+y);
  ctx.moveTo(clipPts[0].x,clipPts[0].y);
  for(var i=1;i<clipPts.length;i++){
    ctx.lineTo(clipPts[i].x,clipPts[i].y);
  }
  ctx.clip();
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
  ctx.restore();
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<h4>Move a clipped area to x==100, y==20</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=600 height=400></canvas>
```